# Making a simulation of congestion control in java

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, simulation

Which java framework is best for making of simulation of TCP's congestion control mechanism. I  have started working with java Applets now But some articles on net makes me confused because they say java applets and awt are outdated.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Applets is that they run in a browser. They have become largely unpopular, due to requiring the Java plugin installed & many security problems with same.

People have been widely recommended to *disable Java plugins* to prevent malware exploits using applet/ Java web start technology, so you will find it difficult to get people to see/ or run any applet you did make.

If you want to make a GUI/ graphical program, use Swing (or conceivably JavaFX) rather than AWT. AWT is grossly outdated.

Unless you really need your simulation to run in a browser, just make it a proper standalone application.

Comment: Nit pick: Swing has an applet as well ;)

Comment: Etc etc, but make it a _stand-alone_ application using Swing rather than an applet if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks.Swings isnt outdated too?? what do you say about JavaFX ??

Comment: If you're doing "graphics on a canvas" for your simulation, it may not matter very much. Swing is more _standard_, I don't think you can really say it's outdated. JavaFX is the new & hyped more-graphical, more-interactive library.. of course we have yet to see whether it's going to catch on, or just disappear like MS Silverlight. I'd use Swing, but I'm conservative.

Comment: Nice answer. One thing that would be good to see in it is, if the OP wants to host the sim in a browser using java, what do you recommend instead of applets, is there something else? If not, Scala + Lift?

Comment: yeah should i use eclipse or netbeans which would be better??